# Getting records from the past x weeks

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, conditional-statements

I've been fighting with an issue about querying the records where `created_at` is within the current, or past x weeks. Say, today is Wednesday, so that'd be from Monday at midnight, up to now, if x = 1. If x > 1, I'm looking for current week, up to today, or past week, but not using regular `interval '1 week'` as that'll get me Wednesday to Wednesday, and I'm only looking into "whole" weeks.

I've tried the interval-solution, and also things like `WHERE created_at > (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '5 week')`.
A solution that'll work for both day, month, year etc, would be preferred, as I'm actually building the query through some other backend logic.

I'm looking for a generic query for "Find everything that's been created 'x periods' back.

---

Edit:

Since last time, I've implemented this in my Ruby on Rails application. This has caused some problems when using HOUR. The built is working for everything but HOUR (MONTH, DAY, and YEAR)

```sql
SELECT "customer_uses".* 
FROM "customer_uses" 
WHERE (customer_uses.created_at > DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', TIMESTAMP '2017-09-17T16:45:01+02:00') - INTERVAL '1 MONTH')
```

Which works correctly on my test cases. (Checking count of this). The TIMESTAMP is generated by `DateTime.now` to ensure my test-cases working with a time-override for "time-travelling"-tests, therefore not using the built in function.

(I've stripped away some extra WHERE-calls which should be irrelevant).

Why the HOUR isn't working is a mystery for me, as I'm using it with a interpolated string for `HOUR` instead of `MONTH` as above like so:

```sql
SELECT "customer_uses".* 
FROM "customer_uses" 
WHERE (customer_uses.created_at > DATE_TRUNC('HOUR', TIMESTAMP '2017-09-17T16:45:21+02:00') - INTERVAL '1 HOUR')
```

Comment: What is wrong with `WHERE created_at > (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '5 week')` ?  Are you asking for several queries here, for any period of time (e.g. month, week)?

Comment: maybe: `where date_trunc('week', created_at) > date_trunc('week', current_date) - interval '5 week'`

Comment: I'm looking for using the beginning of the week. I suppose the query would be "the same", since it'll be `INTERVAL '5 month'` simply, right @TimBiegeleisen?

Comment: @FrederikSpang Your call to `DATE_TRUNC` is [definitely doing its job](http://rextester.com/SMBEK25860), so I'm not sure what the problem is.  What about your query isn't behaving the way you want?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure - I'm just trying out some things in a query. I have automated tests that does the same thing for every 'type' of period. allow 2 pr 'period', make one, test usability, make two: test usability, make 4, ensure unusability. Try and make 4 and "Timetravel" forward, and retry. Only week and  HOUR fails here.

Comment: What I'm doing is https://repl.it/LMpL/3 (With some added Rails models, and a comparison to `self.uses` in the `check`-method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current suggested query is almost right, except that it uses the current date instead of the start of the week:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE created_at > (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '5 week')
```

Instead, we can check 5 week intervals backwards, but from the start of the current week:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE created_at > DATE_TRUNC('week', CURRENT_DATE) - INTERVAL '5 week';
```

I believe you should be able to use the above query as a template for other time periods, e.g. a certain number of months.  Just replace the unit in `DATE_TRUNC` and in the interval of the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Your answer works perfectly, except for using `HOUR`. I've tried adding in a app-rendered `CURRENT_DATE`, for using datetimes, and specifying `DATE_TRUNC('hour', TIMESTAMP '....')`, however this doesn't work for HOUR, but works for DAY, MONTH *and* YEAR. However I've accepted your answer now, as I didn't mention hour in the original answer, and this otherwise works as a charm

Comment: @FrederikSpang I appreciate the upvote, but if you can provide some data in your original question where the hour becomes an issue I'd be happy to look into it.

Comment: Will do. Just a moment.

Comment: Updated with query examples and a more close description.